# How to create a Phar archive without index?

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to make a Phar archive with one of my lib. The lib is just a bunch of classes organized into folders and subfolders. No index.php at all here, just a static Config class to call to initiate the autoloader.

Anyway, I built a archive like this :

```
$phar = new Phar(__DIR__ . '/lis.phar',0,'lib.phar');
$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__ . '/class','/\.php$');
$phar->stopBuffering();
```

After that I'm trying to use the phar like this :

```
require('lib.phar');
Config::register(); // Config is in the phar
```

But I get the following error :

> Warning: include(phar://D:\wamp\www_test\phar\lib.phar/index.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: phar error: "index.php" is
>   not a file in phar "D:/wamp/www/_test/phar/lib.phar" in
>   D:\wamp\www_test\phar\lib.phar on line 9

How can I make a phar archive without any index.php file inside it ? In fact I just need the archive to be a container for my files, no need to auto execute anything.

Comment: I think you didn't show the code in which you add the stub. Run {{$phar->getStub();}} to see your stub code.

Comment: The previous code is the entire code i use to create the phar. I don't use any *stub() method.

Comment: did you try to check if you have stub code as I advised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i think you have to `startBuffering()` before `stopBuffering()`. And I might think that `buildFromDirectory` does this internally for you.
You don't need to do `stopBuffering()` for "sealing" the archive. Its ready "on the fly".

So second: You can watch the defaultStub (which is used in your code implicity) like this:

```
$phar->setDefaultStub();
var_dump($phar->getStub());
```

Its a littly bit cryptic, but you will figure it out. It does check for phar stream wrapper support (in 5.3) and if not it extracts the contents to temp file and then executes the `Phar::START` constant File - which is by default "index.php". And of course it does `Phar::interceptFileFuncs()` and sets the include path, which makes the phar working "magic". But your question sounds like you only need an archive for your libs. So you're better off with using the "PharData" class. Haven't tried it yet, but the documentation says so.